# Returning an object pointer from a recursive function met with access violation

Tags: c++, pointers, graph, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I've created a simple recursive function that performs preorder traversal to return a node that matches a target string.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Node {
    public:
    string value;
    Node *left, *right;

    Node(string value) {
        this->value = value;
        this->left = NULL;
        this->right = NULL;
    }
};

class Tree {
    public:
    Node* preorder(Node* root, string target) {
        if (root == NULL) return NULL;

        if (root->value == target) {
            return root;
        }

        preorder(root->left, target);
        preorder(root->right, target);
    }
};

int main() {
    Node* a = new Node("a");
    Node* b = new Node("b");
    Node* c = new Node("c");
    Node* d = new Node("d");

    a->left = b;
    a->right = c;
    c->left = d;

    Tree t = Tree();
    Node* found = t.preorder(a, "d");
    cout << found->value << endl;
}
```

The traversal is done correctly, but the program doesn't print anything. I just get a `[Done] exited with code=3221225477 in 2.038 seconds` after compiling with g++ and running.

Where did I mess up with the pointers?

Comment: What should `preorder` return in the end of block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preorder` doesn't return anything in yhe recursive cases. The behaviour of the program is unrefined.

Hint for future: Use compiler warnings.